# Interval for convergence for $x\ln x$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Find a series expansion for $x\ln x $ in powers of $(x-1)$ and determine the values for $x$ for which the expansion is valid.

**Attempt**
$$y\ln y = \int 1+\ln y\,dx = \int1+\ln(\frac{y}{e}+1)\,dx= y+\sum^\infty_0\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)e^n}y^{n+1}$$
$$y=(x-1)$$
$$x\ln x = \int 1+\ln x\,dx = \int1+\ln(\frac{x}{e}+1)\,dx= x-1+\sum^\infty_0\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)e^n}(x-1)^{n+1}$$

I have some confusions.

$1.$ I made the substitution weirdly. At some places, I substituted $x$ and at some, I substituted $x-1$. I am aware the placements are correct since $x-1$ has t come after the expansion and $x$ before the expansion and I am also aware the reason behind this statement. What I want to know is how to write this expansion in mathematical terms so the substitutions don't seem mathematically inaccurate.

$2.$ The interval for convergence for $\ln(1+x)$ at $x=1$ is $(0,2]$, yet for $\int \ln(1+\frac{x}{e})$ at $x=1$ is $[0,2]$. Why is that? Is it because integration implies the integrated function is continous at $0$ and thus y Abel's Theorem the series converges at $x=0$.

Comment: Where does the equality $\int1+\ln y\,\mathrm dy=\int1+\ln\left(\frac ye+1\right)\,\mathrm dy$ come from?

Comment: 1) I'd advise $$\int_{\text{thing we do not write for show}}^{\text{see below}} f(x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

I would just write\begin{align*}x\ln x&=\bigl(1+(x-1)\bigr)\left((x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}2+\frac{(x-1)^3}3-\frac{(x-1)^4}4+\cdots\right)\\&=(x-1)+\left(-\frac12+1\right)(x-1)^2+\left(\frac13-\frac12\right)(x-1)^3+\left(-\frac14+\frac13\right)(x-1)^4+\cdots\\&=(x-1)+\frac{(x-1)^2}2-\frac{(x-1)^3}6+\frac{(x-1)^4}{12}+\cdots\\&=(x-1)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(x-1)^n}{n(n-1)}.\end{align*}The radius of convergence is $1$, of course.

Comment: The thing I am concerned is the INTERVAL of convergence for ln x is (-1,1] but for xlnx it is [-1,1]. Why is the series expansion for xlnx convergent at x=-1 when it is not for ln x?

Comment: @FaiqRaees This series converges when (and only when) $|x-1|\leqslant1$, that is, when $x\in[0,2]$. It converges when $x=0$ because then we get the convergent series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{-1}{n(n-1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

To make life simpler, let $x=t+1$ and look at the series expansion of $$y=(1+t)\log(1+t)$$ around $t=0$.

You know the series expansion of $\log(1+t)$. Then, $\cdots$.

When done, replace $t$ by $(x-1)$

Comment: The thing I am concerned is the INTERVAL of convergence for ln x is (-1,1] but for xlnx it is [-1,1]. Why is the series expansion for xlnx convergent at x=-1 when it is not for ln x?

Answer (score 0):

Put $u=x-1$ so we have

$$(u+1)\log(u+1) = (u+1) \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} = \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \left(\frac{u^{n+2}}{n+1} + \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}\right) = \color{#f00}{\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \left(u^{k+1} + u^k\right)} = \sum_{k \geq 1} a_ku^k = \sum_{k \geq 1} a_k (x-1)^{k}$$

where $a_k = \begin{cases}
1  & k=1 \\
\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} + \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k-1}  & \text{else}
\end{cases}$

Finding the appropriate $a_k$ sequence requires a mild amount of cleverness with the *red* series.

The interval of convergence is quite clearly $[0,2]$.

Comment: The thing I am concerned is the INTERVAL of convergence for ln x is (-1,1] but for xlnx it is [-1,1]. Why is the series expansion for xlnx convergent at x=-1 when it is not for ln x?

Comment: @FaiqRaees That was a mistake. It should be $[0, 2]$. I was thinking in terms of the $u$ variable.